# What is a pi mapping in topology?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I am going through Homotopy theory from the following book :

https://archive.org/details/borisovichbliznyakovizrailevichfomenkointroductiontotopologymir/mode/2up

At page 125, of this book , The homotopy group of a space gets introduced .

And it starts with an appeal to the reader to note that for every topological space , $\ Y $ , and continuous mapping $ f :  X_1 \rightarrow X_2 $ of topological spaces  there corresponds the natural mapping : 
 $\pi^y(f)  : \pi(X_2,Y) - \pi(X_1,Y)$

I could not understand what this $\pi $ mapping is as maybe because I am starting directly from homotopy in this book, but I tried searching for this mapping in whole book but could not find it. Maybe I missed it in the previous contents of the book.

I guess this is a generally used notion in mathematics. So if it is a general notion, what exactly is the definition of this pi mapping. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that $\pi(X,Y)$ is the set of homotopy classes of continuous maps $X\to Y$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks a lot . Anyway by which you could support the likeliness of this ?

Comment: Because of the way the induced functions look and because then the author defines $\pi_n(X,x_0)$ as $\pi((I^n,\partial (I^n));(X,x_0))$. However, I cannot find in the chapter a definition of that notation $\pi(X;Y)$ either.

Comment: @Gae.S. : Thanks a lot , Apparently it seems so that it means the homotopy class of continuous maps from X -> Y. However, it is quite surprising that an introduction to it is absent .

Comment: @Gae.S. By the way in the line that begins with Similarly which is towards the end of the screenshot  do you find it stating anything different than the line starting after the heading of homtopy group of a space ?

Answer (score 1):

The map $\pi^Y(f)$ is a mapping which takes some equivalence class of maps $[\phi]: X_2 \rightarrow Y$ to the equivalence class maps $[\phi \circ f]: X_1 \rightarrow Y$. Of course it is left to show that this map is actually well defined i.e. that for $[\phi] = [\sigma]$ in $\pi(X_2, Y)$ we have $[\phi \circ f] = [\sigma \circ f]$ in $\pi(X_1, Y)$.

This is a special case of a (contravariant) functor between categories. Here between the (naive) homotopy category of topological spaces and sets. In fact, it is a special instance of a hom-functor. In general, let $\mathcal{A}$ be a category. Then a (contravariant) hom-functor $F_Y$ (based at an object $Y \in \mathcal{A}$) is a functor $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ s.t. for any object $B \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $F_Y(B) = \text{Hom}(B,Y)$. On a morphism $f: A \rightarrow B$, the image under functor $F_Y(f)$ is a morphism $F_Y(B) = \text{Hom}(B,Y) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,Y) = F_Y(A)$. It takes an element $\phi \in \text{Hom}(B,Y)$, that is a map $\phi: B \rightarrow Y$ to a map $\phi \circ f: A \rightarrow Y$ i.e. an element in $\text{Hom}(A,Y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot , although I would need some time to go over it

Comment: Few points in your answer that I would like to understand . 
In the line when you say "this is a special case of a contravariant functor between catagories ...Here between the homotopy category of topological spaces and sets . 

Did you mean topological (spaces and sets) or (toplogical spaces) and sets ?

Comment: @beerzilcharlemagne Between the homotopy category of topological spaces and the category of sets.